# Paypal throw error after push 'buynow' button on live but not in sandbox

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I create a encrypted button and in sandbox all works fine, but in live after push paid button paypal show me this error:

La dirección de correo electrónico para la empresa no se incluye en el objeto binario. Comuníquese con el vendedor.

Sorry I can't make this error to be in english.

What email is not present, business, custmer?

This start to happend after I change certificates for new ones, those ones you have to upload to paypal to encrypt buttons.

Thanks

Pablo

Answer (score 0):

It's referring to the businesses email address. It is not present. It doesn't matter if the customers address is present until the actual payment processes.

Also, what language is this in?

Comment: You mean than I'm not putting my business email when I generate the button? Why in sandbox works? 
PHP

Answer (score 0):

ok, I found the problem, the certificates were wrong

Thanks